# KeyError: False in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd

businesses = pd.read_json(businesses_filepath, lines=True, encoding='utf_8')
restaurantes = businesses['Restaurants' in businesses['categories']]
```

I would like to remove the lines that do not have Restaurants in the categories column, and this column has lists, however gave the error 'KeyError: False' and I would like to understand why and how to solve.

Comment: `'Restaurants' in businesses['categories']` is a native python expression that evaluates to the scalar `False` (or `True`). Is `'Restaurants'` not simply one of the categories? In that case you need `businesses[businesses.categories == 'Restaurants']`.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The expression `'Restaurants' in businesses['categories']` returns the boolean value `False`. This is passed to the brackets indexing operator for the DataFrame businesses which does not contain a column called False and thus raises a KeyError.

What you are looking to do is something called boolean indexing which works like this.

```
businesses[businesses['categories'] == 'Restaurants']
```

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue in my code: ```df.loc[('Error:' in df['Quick Insights'])```
Problem is that I need the ```in``` part, as the word "Error:" is just a substring of ```quick insights```. How would you address that? Is there any operator that acts like SQL's ```like```?

Comment: solved using ```df[df['Quick Insights'].str.match('(Error:)', na=False)]```

Answer (score 6):

The reason for this is that the `Series` class implements a custom `in` operator that doesn't return an `iterable` like the `==` does, here's a workaround

```py
businesses[['Restaurants' in c for c in list(businesses['categories'])]]
```

hopefully this helps someone where you're looking for a substring in the column and not a full match.

Comment: I'm considering just regex matching what I'm looking for, turning it into a new column and indexing using the new column

Answer (score 5):

If you find that your data contains spelling variations or alternative restaurant related terms, the following may be of benefit. Essentially you put your restaurant related terms in `restuarant_lst`. The `lambda` function returns `true` if any of the items in `restaurant_lst` are contained within each row of the business series. The `.loc` indexer filters out rows which return `false` for the `lambda` function.

```
restaurant_lst = ['Restaurant','restaurantes','diner','bistro']
restaurant = businesses.loc[businesses.apply(lambda x: any(restaurant_str in x for restaurant_str in restaurant_lst))]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you meant was :

```
businesses = businesses.loc[businesses['categories'] == 'Restaurants']
```

that will only keep rows with the category restaurants

Answer (score 0):

None of the answers here actually worked for me,

```
businesses[businesses['categories'] == 'Restaurants']
```

obviously won't work since the value in 'categories' is not a string, it's a list, meaning the comparison will always fail.

What **does**, however, work, is converting the column into tuples instead of strings:

```
businesses['categories'] = businesses['categories'].apply(tuple)
```

That allows you to use the standard .loc thing:

```
businesses.loc[businesses['categories'] == ('Restaurants',)]
```