# Selecting rows of a DataFrame according to whether an element is in a column's list

Tags: python, pandas

I currently have a DataFrame like such:

```
      col1      col2            col3
 0     0         1         ['a', 'b', 'c']
 1     2         3         ['d', 'e', 'f']
 2     4         5         ['g', 'h', 'i']
```

what I want to do is select the rows where a certain value is contained in the lists of `col3`. For example, the code I would initially run is:

```
df.loc['a' in df['col3']]
```

but I get the following error:

```
KeyError: False
```

I've taken a look at this question: [KeyError: False in pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44875397/keyerror-false-in-pandas-dataframe) but it doesn't quite answer my question. I've tried the suggested solutions in the answers and it didn't help.

How would I go about this issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use list comprehension for test each list:

```
df1 = df[['a' in x for x in df['col3']]]
print (df1)
   col1  col2       col3
0     0     1  [a, b, c]
```

Or use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
df1 = df[df['col3'].map(lambda x: 'a' in x)]
#alternative
#df1 = df[df['col3'].apply(lambda x: 'a' in x)]
```

Or create `DataFrame` and test by [`DataFrame.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html) with [`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html):

```
df1 = df[pd.DataFrame(df['col3'].tolist()).eq('a').any(axis=1)]
```

Comment: pandas expert jezreal a real live saver

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
df = df[df.testc.map(lambda x: 'a' in x)]
```